# Drop Down menu selection does not navigate to link

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created a drop down menu in bootstrap. I have set the links using php code to site my path. (I tried it without php and I still get the same result)
When I select the item and click the submit button to pull the categories nothing happens.

I created a link menu using the same paths and it works, as soon as I put it in a drop down menu with a button it does not work.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <select class="form-control selecter">
        <option selected="selected" value="">All Categories</option>
        <option value="<?php echo base_url();?>categories/posts/154">Auto</option>
        <option value="<?php echo base_url();?>categories/posts/154">House</option>
        <option value="<?php echo base_url();?>categories/posts/154">Lawn</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-gradient">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <option> will not redirect to any link. If this is the case, you should use javascript, window.location.href to navigate on select change event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not navigate using `option`, If you want to navigate on the `option` change or the `button` click, you should use JavaScript `addEventListener` method to listen for the events. Ex: `click` in button or `change` in select drop-down. By using `window.location` property you can navigate to page

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
    <div class="col-md-5">
         <select id="dropdown" class="form-control selecter">
             <option selected="selected" value="">All Categories</option>
             <option value="<?php echo base_url();?>categories/posts/154">Auto</option>
             <option value="<?php echo base_url();?>categories/posts/154">House</option>
             <option value="<?php echo base_url();?>categories/posts/154">Lawn</option>
         </select>
            <br>
         <button id="search" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-gradient">Search</button>

   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

VANILLA JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
let dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
let searchBtn = document.getElementById('search');

searchBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   window.location =  dropdown.value;
}

// If you want to navigate when the selection option gets changed

dropdown.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
   window.location =  dropdown.value;
} </script>
```

JQUERY

```
<script>
    $(function(){
     // On option select navigation
      $('#dropdown').on('change', function () {
          var url = $(this).val(); 
          if (url) { 
              window.location = url;
          }

      });

      // On Search button click - navigation
      $('#search').on('click', function () {
          var url = $('#dropdown').val(); 
          if (url) { 
              window.location = url;
          }

      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a select element no a link or a `form` action. The default behaviour of the `select` will be to select the option and not link to the option value.

You will you need to fire a JavaScript when `search` button is clicked and then redirect the user to the selected value.

```js
function search()
{
 var id = document.getElementById("selecter");
 window.location = id.options[id.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
<div class="col-md-5">
            <select class="form-control selecter" id="selecter">
              <option selected="selected" value="">All Categories</option>

              <option value="<?php echo base_url();?>categories/posts/154">Auto</option>
              <option value="<?php echo base_url();?>categories/posts/154">House</option>
              <option value="<?php echo base_url();?>categories/posts/154">Lawn</option>


            </select>
            <br>

            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-gradient" onclick="javascript:search()">Search</button>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```